# $A$ is fundamental if and only if For any $x^*\in X^*$ with the property that $x^*=0$ on $A$ it follows that $x^*=0$ on $X.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In [Exercises in Functional Analysis](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402015601) by Costara, Chapter $8,$ Applications for the Hahn-Banach Theorem, the authors stated the following Theorem:

> **Theorem**: Let $X$ be a normed space, or more generally, a Hausdorff locally convex space, and $A\subseteq X.$
>   Then the following assertions are equivalent:
>
> $(1)$ $A$ is fundamental, that is, linear hull of $A$ is dense in $X;$
>
> $(2)$ For any $x^*\in X^*$ with the property that $x^*=0$ on $A$ it follows that $x^*=0$ on $X.$

I tried to prove the above by myself, however, to no avail.

If possible, I would like to see a proof of the above equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ implies $(2)$: let $H$ denote the linear hull of $A$. If $x^*\in X^*$ such that $x^*=0$ on $A$, then $x^*=0$ on $H$, by linearity. If $x \in X$, then there is a sequence $(h_n)$ in $H$ with $h_n \to x$. Since $x^*$ is continuous,we get $0=x^*(h_n) \to x^*(x)$ and therefore $x^*(x)=0$.

$(2)$ implies $(1)$: again let $H$ denote the linear hull of $A$. Suppose that $Y: = \overline{H} \ne X$. Then $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and there is $x \in X$ with $x \notin Y$. By Hahn-Banach, thewre is $x^* \in X^*$ such that $x*=0$ on $Y$ and $x^*(x) \ne 0$.
We have: $x*=0$ on $A$, but $ x*=0$ on$ X$ is not true, a contradiction.